# Problems with threads, making a game in Java

Tags: java

I'm doing a Snake game in Java. I have the basic functionability, but I want pause the game when I click on a button. But the problem I have is when I clic on this button, the game is paused, but when I click again the game doesn't recognize the controls. I have a method called Init, on this I initialize the thread "Hilo". I tried to make a second thread in which I put an actionPerformed for the button, but the problem continued, now I am more confused. Here is my code:

```
Thread hilo; //I declared the thread
String state=""; //It is for control de state (paused or no)

Runnable hiloFor = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        Thread actual = Thread.currentThread();
        synchronized(actual) 
        {
            do
            {
                //Game instructions (there are a lot of them)
                if(state.equals("paused")) 
                {
                    actual.wait();
                }

            }while(!option.equals("Exit"));
        }
    }
};


//This is my action performed where I control if it is paused
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if ( e.getSource() == btnPause )
    { 

        if(state.equals("paused")) 
        {
            cont(); //method for reactive the thread
            state="";
        }else if(state.equals(""))
        {
            state="paused";
        }
    }

}
```

If somebody can help me, I will be very glad, It has turned difficult to me.

Comment: You can't tell the current thread to process any further input if you've told it to wait...

Comment: oh, and what do you suggest? I'm confused, I have used threads but not in games, I only want to pause the game and reanude it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(state.equals("paused")) 
{
    actual.wait();
}
```

This part actually pauses the thread, until it's told to start it's work again. I suppose what you wanted in this case is something like `continue;` in loop, which, although, is not a very elegant way to do this. More suitable way to do this would be using `notify()`.

Answer (score 1):

To reactivate the Thread in `wait()` you must call `notify()` (or better `notifyAll()`) on the same object.

Your code looks like you expect to pause the Thread you call `wait()` on. This is not the case. `wait()` will always pause the thread making the call, not the object that is the target. You can use any object for the `wait()` / `notifyAll()` signaling, it just has to be the same object for both sides of the communication.

This pages has some good explanations: http://javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_wait_notify.shtml